# drop down flickers in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a drop down box which works perfectly in Chrome and IE.

It works fine in Firefox, until the scroll bar is used in the drop down list.

If I click the drop down, and it drops down, and I make a selection - it works fine.

If I click the drop down, scroll down the drop down list and make a selection - the screen flickers.

It only seems to do this flickering if the scroll bar is used to navigate down the drop down list, if the scroll bar remains at the top of the list and a selection is made, it works fine

Any body had a similar issue? It is not my computer, we've tested it on multiple - it seems to be an issue with Firefox and when the drop down scroll bar is used.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ")

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more details. There is no such thing as a "drop down" in HTML/CSS. Either you mean a `select` element, or some JavaScript-built UI element. Which is it? In either case you'll need to show some code or a working example.

Comment: Some example code is needed. Please try to put together a jsFiddle so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

When I use focus in function to display drop down select option 1,2,3 .drop down disappears  when we click on it in IE and fire fox.

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer. Why does this work? What was the issue that you resolved? That makes it easier for OP and everyone in the future to understand their problem.